Can the generalized Stokes' and Change of Variables theorems be interpreted rigorously in terms of adjoint-like operators?
The generalized Change of Variables theorem asserts that
$
\int_{\varphi(\Omega)} \omega = \int_{\Omega} \varphi^*(\omega),
$
where $\varphi: \Omega \to \varphi(\Omega)$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, $\omega$ is a differential form on $\varphi(\Omega)$, and $\varphi^*(\omega)$ is its pullback to $\Omega$.
This equation seems to exhibit a behavior reminiscent of an adjoint operator. For instance, if we define a pairing
$
\langle D, \eta \rangle := \int_D \eta,
$
where $D$ is a domain and $\eta$ is a top-degree differential form, then the result can be rephrased as:
$
\langle \varphi(\Omega), \omega \rangle = \langle \Omega, \varphi^*(\omega) \rangle.
$
This analogy leads me to wonder if there is a way to formalize this resemblance to adjoint operators in a rigorous mathematical framework.
Similarly, the Stokes' theorem states that
$
\int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_M d\omega,
$
where $\omega$ is an $(n-1)$-form, $M$ is a manifold with boundary, and $\dim(M) = n$. This too can be expressed as:
$
\langle \partial M, \omega \rangle = \langle M, d\omega \rangle,
$
suggesting that $d$ and $\partial$ are, in some sense, duals or adjoints. Here also, I am trying to understand this adjoint-like relationship in a more rigorous way.

Is there a set-theoretic, measure-theoretic, or category-theoretic way to interpret this relationship rigorously?
Could this be connected to some notion of duality or adjunction in category theory?
Is there an existing framework in differential geometry or topology where this "adjoint-like" behavior is made explicit?

I’m particularly interested in any insights or references that explore this analogy or develop it further. While this isn’t strictly about understanding differential geometry or topology, I believe there’s value in exploring such perspectives, as they often reveal deeper connections.
Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

First of all, this has nothing to do with Stokes' Theorem. Secondly, the result you claim to be a theorem is wrong as stated. Where did you find it?

@MoisheKohan Sorry for the error, it is the Change of Variables formula.

@MoisheKohan Thanks for pointing out ! I totally overlooked that !

@MoisheKohan I have edited a bit!

Read about currents. In that framework, manifolds and differential forms are incorporated into one notion.

Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225723/is-stokes-theorem-natural-in-the-sense-of-category-theory (which is the first search result when entering "Stokes theorem category theory" into site search). Please clarify if this answers your question.

I am not sure why you think this is an adjunction, the two inputs of the pairing don't have the same type.

@MartinBrandenburg I have working knowledge of Categories but honestly I do not have expertise in hardcore category theory. However, this notation suggest something sort of adjunction is going on here. Of course, this is not adjoint of inner product, since the inputs are different, but I still can't help thinking that there is surely a way to make it rigorous.

@TedShifrin Kindly elaborate a little bit for me.

Re  currents, start here. Then look at Morgan's Geometric Measure Theory: A Beginner's Guide.

@TedShifrin Thank you very much!
